# Subsetting data by multiple date ranges - R

Tags: r, subset

I'll get straight to the point: I have been given some data sets in .csv format containing regularly logged sensor data from a machine. However, this data set also contains measurements taken when the machine is turned off, which I would like to separate from the data logged from when it is turned on. To subset the relevant data I also have a file containing start and end times of these shutdowns. This file is several hundred rows long.

Examples of the relevant files for this problem:

```
file: sensor_data.csv

sens_name,time,measurement
sens_A,17/12/11 06:45,32.3321
sens_A,17/12/11 08:01,36.1290
sens_B,17/12/11 05:32,17.1122
sens_B,18/12/11 03:43,12.3189

##################################################

file: shutdowns.csv

shutdown_start,shutdown_end
17/12/11 07:46,17/12/11 08:23
17/12/11 08:23,17/12/11 09:00
17/12/11 09:00,17/12/11 13:30
18/12/11 01:42,18/12/11 07:43
```

To subset data in R, I have previously used the `subset()` function with simple conditions which has worked fine, but I don't know how to go about subsetting sensor data which fall outside multiple shutdown date ranges. I've already formatted the date and time data using `as.POSIXlt()`.

I'm suspecting some scripting may be involved to come up with a good solution, but I'm afraid I am not yet experienced enough to handle this type of data.

Any help, advice, or solutions will be greatly appreciated. Let me know if there's anything else needed for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `POSIXct` format for ranges within data frames. We create an index for sensors operating during shutdowns with `t < shutdown_start OR t > shutdown_end`. With these ranges we can then subset the data as necessary:

```
posixct <- function(x) as.POSIXct(x, format="%d/%m/%y %H:%M")

sensor_data$time <- posixct(sensor_data$time)
shutdowns[] <- lapply(shutdowns, posixct)

ind1 <- sapply(sensor_data$time, function(t) {
  sum(t < shutdowns[,1] | t > shutdowns[,2]) == length(sensor_data$time)})

#Measurements taken when shutdown
sensor_data[ind1,]
#   sens_name                time measurement
# 1    sens_A 2011-12-17 06:45:00     32.3321
# 3    sens_B 2011-12-17 05:32:00     17.1122

#Measurements taken when not shutdown
sensor_data[!ind1,]
#   sens_name                time measurement
# 2    sens_A 2011-12-17 08:01:00     36.1290
# 4    sens_B 2011-12-18 03:43:00     12.3189
```

Comment: Many thanks, Pierre! I even learned a few things from your code. However, I am having trouble with `ind1` after completing your steps. Typing `summary(ind1)` shows that every single row was valued as FALSE. I suspect this is related to the "filtering condition" inside `function(t)`, but I haven't been able to find a solution myself. Is there something I have missed? Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Hello again. I'm still trying to figure this out and have gotten stuck at trying to understand the role of the `sum()` function inside `function(t)`. With `sapply()` you're taking individual measurement times from `sensor_data$time` and then evaluating whether each fulfills the condition within `function(t)`, right? Does the `sum()` function help in seeing whether sensor_data times are within **any** shutdown interval?

Comment: Using `sum` in the function is a way to count the amount of TRUEs vs FALSEs. Try `sum(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))` to see how it adds.

Comment: this might be easier `function(t) all(t < shutdowns[,1] | t > shutdowns[,2])`