# filter/subset a dataframe based on multiple time periods in R

Tags: r, filter, subset

I need to filter or subset a large (100,000+ rows) dataframe using multiple time periods.  I basically need to remove rows in the dataframe that have date/time between the start date/times and end date/times in the time period table. I found this post describing my question ([Subsetting data by multiple date ranges - R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357101/subsetting-data-by-multiple-date-ranges-r)), but I can't seem to get the code to work.  Any advice is appreciated. See below for example data.

```
time period table:
start,end
7/26/2017 14:05,7/26/2017 16:05
8/24/2017 13:40,8/24/2017 15:40
6/29/2017 20:45,6/30/2017 0:41

dataframe:
time,temp.c,lux,serial.num
6/29/2017 20:40,33.63,0,20168779
6/29/2017 20:40,33.11,0,20168780
6/29/2017 20:50,20.42,602.8,20148333
6/29/2017 20:50,20.32,721.2,20148334
6/29/2017 20:50,19.75,3788.9,20148335
7/26/2017 16:00,22.9,183,20168779
7/26/2017 16:00,23.29,1237.9,20168780
7/26/2017 16:10,23.38,1173.3,20148333
7/26/2017 16:10,23.67,839.6,20148334
8/24/2017 15:40,24.06,387.5,20168780
8/24/2017 15:50,23.58,0,20148332
```

Answer (score 0):

**Data:**

```
time_period_table <- data.frame(start=c('7/26/2017 14:05', '8/24/2017 13:40', '6/29/2017 20:45'), end=c('7/26/2017 16:05', '8/24/2017 15:40', '6/30/2017 0:41'))
time_period_table $start <- as.POSIXct(time_period_table $start, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
time_period_table $end <- as.POSIXct(time_period_table $end, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

time_period_table
```

[image]

**Keep rows in dataframe with date/time between start date/time and end date/time:**

```
keep_by_date_time <- function(data_frame, start_date, start_time, end_date, end_time) {
    from <- paste(start_date, start_time)
    to <- paste(end_date, end_time)
    sub_frame <- subset(data_frame, start >= as.POSIXct(from) & end <= as.POSIXct(to))
    return(sub_frame)
}
```

**Usage:**

```
# return rows with date and time between July 26, 2017 at 1:05pm and July 26, 2017 at 5:05pm:

keep_by_date_time(time_period_table, '2017-07-26', '13:05', '2017-07-26', '17:05')
```

[image]

***Remove* rows in dataframe with date/time between start date/time and end date/time:**

```
remove_by_date_time <- function(data_frame, start_date, start_time, end_date, end_time) {
    from <- paste(start_date, start_time)
    to <- paste(end_date, end_time)
    rem_row <- which(time_period_table$start >= as.POSIXct(from) & time_period_table$end <= as.POSIXct(to))
    rem_frame <- data_frame[-rem_row,]
    return(rem_frame)
}
```

**Usage:**

```
# remove rows with date and time between August 20, 2017 at 1:05pm and August 26, 2017 at 5:05pm:

remove_by_date_time(time_period_table, '2017-08-20', '13:05', '2017-08-26', '17:05')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code.  I have to remove data between several sets of dates for several dataframes.  I have tried this code but something I am doing is not right. Also, I want rows in the data_frame not between dates in the shutdown table.                                                                     
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data_frame$time <- mdy_hm(data_frame$time)
shutdown$start <- mdy_hm(shutdown$start)
shutdown$end <- mdy_hm(shutdown$end)

filter(data_frame, time %in% shutdown[between (shutdown, start, end)])

Comment: Pretend you had a function that did what you want. What would it look like? Would this be it:  remove_rows_with_these_dates(list_of_dataframes, list_of_startend_dates)? Does the same set of start/end dates apply to all data frames, or does each dataframe have its own set?

Comment: Yes, that function would do what I need to do.